# R - how to loop through a dataframe to match multiple substrings - concatenate all matches in a new column

Tags: r

I am quite new to R - have worked on this all day but am out of ideas.

I have a dataframe with long descriptions in one column, eg:
`df`:

```
ID  Name  Description
 1  A     ABC DEF
 2  B     ARS XUY
 3  C     ASD
```

And I have a vector of search terms:

```
ABC
ARS
XUY
DE
```

I would like to go through each row in the dataframe and search the `Description` for any of the search terms. I then want all matches to be concatenated in a new column in the dataframe, e.g.:

```
ID  Name  Description  Matches
 1  A     ABC DEF      ABC
 2  B     ARS XUY      ARS;XUY
 3  C     ASD
```

I would want to search ~100k rows with 1000 search terms.
Does anyone have any ideas? I was able to get a matrix with `sapply` and `grepl`, but I'd rather have a concatenated solution.

Comment: Assume your variable of search terms is called `terms`. `library(stringr); regex = paste(terms, collapse="|"); df$Matches = paste(str_extract(df$Description, regex), collapse="; ")` should give you what you want. I'm on mobile though and can't test right now.

Comment: Might have to do `df$Matches = lapply(str_extract(df$Description,  regex), function(x) paste(x, collapse="; "))`

Comment: Why isn't `DE` matched in the first row?

Comment: @HaddE.Nuff you're absolutely right, I would want DE to partial match with DEF - overlooked that. Thanks.

Comment: If DE can match DEF, can ABC match LABC? And if so, should `df$Matches` contain the value from `df$Description`, or the search term that was used to find the match?

Comment: Yes to both DEF and LABC. For the return in $Matches, what would be easier? Ideally, it would contain the search term used to find the match.

Comment: @Brittenb, I tried your first solution, and it gave me the same result across all rows - "ABC; ARS; NA" which I believe is just what was found across all descriptions.

Comment: Second method worked! I'll now go try on my real data, but you answered my question regardless - thank you!

Comment: @Brittenb, on my real data I got a partial success. Your code only returned one match for each Description (where there were any). Any thoughts on what I could try to fix this?

Comment: Yes, use `str_extract_all` instead of `str_extract`. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: That worked! Please, do not apologize. I marked your response below as correct. Also, question - I removed NA from my regex vector, but I'm still getting a lot of NA in the match results. How can I prevent it matching NAs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option, which I tried to use in the comments, is to use the `stringr` package. There are two potential downsides to this approach: 1) it uses regex, and 2) it returns the search term matched instead of the value found.

```
library(stringr)
df = data.frame(Name=LETTERS[1:3], 
                Description=c("ABC DEF", "ARS XUY", "ASD"),
                stringsAsFactors=F)
search_terms = c("ABC", "ARS", "XUY", "DE")
regex = paste(search_terms, collapse="|")
df$Matches = sapply(str_extract_all(df$Description, regex), function(x) paste(x, collapse=";"))
df
#    Name Description Matches
#   (chr)       (chr)   (chr)
# 1     A     ABC DEF  ABC;DE
# 2     B     ARS XUY ARS;XUY
# 3     C         ASD
```

With that being said, I think Alistaire's solution is the better approach since it doesn't use regex.

Comment: This works great - one quirk is that returns NAs (one or multiple) occasionally, but on other rows with no matches, $match is blank. I don't have NA in the terms vector. I can remove them after the fact, so still a good solution. Thanks!

Comment: You could tweak it to use `df$Matches = sapply(str_extract_all(df$Description, regex), function(x) ifelse(length(x) > 0, paste(x, collapse=";"), ""))` instead. That should take care of your issue.

Comment: I apologize - I am an idiot. The list I was working with actually had a "NA" in it. Thank you so much for all of your help!

Comment: I instead used x[!is.na(x)] in your function, NAs were being generated by blank Description

Answer (score 2):

One option using `strsplit` and `%in%` instead of regex:

```
df$Matches <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$Description), '\\s'), 
                     function(x){paste(search[search %in% x], collapse = ';')})
df
#   ID Name Description Matches
# 1  1    A     ABC DEF     ABC
# 2  2    B     ARS XUY ARS;XUY
# 3  3    C         ASD
```

---

#### data:

```
search <- c("ABC", "ARS", "XUY", "DE")
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:3, Name = structure(1:3, .Label = c("A", 
          "B", "C"), class = "factor"), Description = structure(1:3, .Label = c("ABC DEF", 
          "ARS XUY", "ASD"), class = "factor"), Matches = c("ABC", "ARS;XUY", 
          "")), .Names = c("ID", "Name", "Description", "Matches"), row.names = c(NA, 
          -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Alistaire - this ALMOST worked. I got multiple results for some rows, but not others. Could you think of possible reasons?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c(1L,2L,3L),Name=c('A','B','C'),Description=c('ABC DEF','ARS XUY','ASD'),stringsAsFactors=F);
st <- c('ABC','ARS','XUY','DE');
df$Matches <- apply(sapply(paste0('\\b',st,'\\b'),grepl,df$Description),1L,function(m) paste(collapse=';',st[m]));
df;
##   ID Name Description Matches
## 1  1    A     ABC DEF     ABC
## 2  2    B     ARS XUY ARS;XUY
## 3  3    C         ASD
```